# Using Soundcloud API

Tags: api, soundcloud

I am trying to develop an app that features my private content from soundcloud.  When I make my tracks private, it also blocks access to my app.  I checked with soundclouds terms and conditions and it appears that what I'm trying to do is acceptable, but I don't know how to brodge the 2 together.

By using soundclouds api, is there a way to make my tracks private to the public yet grant access to an app?

Has anyone else he challenges with this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Per the document you must authenticate yourself within the application.  You will then have access to your private sounds and can stream them to the public.  Please see the documentation linked [here](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#playing)